# Can I get the resulting Big Query SQL from a query string and a list of positional parameters?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using the Java library to connect to Big Query and get data. I'd like to display back to the user what the final SQL was, with its positional parameters inserted. Is that possible? I've looked through the [QueryJobConfiguration Builder api](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/QueryJobConfiguration.Builder.html) and in some other classes, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Unfortunately a feature like this does not yet exist on the API. It might be better to create a feature request in [java bigquery repository](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/issues) as this feature is really helpful.